# Cannot ping pc from openwrt router

Tags: networking, router, windows-8.1, openwrt

I am trying to set up a port forwarding on a openwrt router, but met a problem (subj).

I can access some of wired connections (192.168.1.221 - linux), but cannot to other ones of them (192.168.1.141 - win8.1). Firewall is disabled.

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ping 192.168.1.221
PING 192.168.1.221 (192.168.1.221): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.221: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.426 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.221: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.384 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.221: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.383 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.221: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.403 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.221 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.383/0.399/0.426 ms
root@OpenWrt:~# ping 192.168.1.141
PING 192.168.1.141 (192.168.1.141): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.1.141 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Why I can't connect to 192.168.1.141?

Comment: Can you try a TCP connection to a port instead of ping? Does ping the other way around work?

Comment: Can you provide some topology of your network? Are there wireless devices/routers involved?

Comment: What version of OpenWRT exactly?  Are you 100% there is a device at `192.168.1.141`?

Comment: As golimar points out, you should try an actual connection - ICMP indicates only IP connectivity and nothing higher. It also isn't required that the host produces an echo reply to a request sent to it in order to make connections at a higher layer. If you are testing port forwarding, telnet is a great tool to ensure connectivity on specific ports is available. Netcat is also a good tool to use.